# How do I deal with Pandas Series data type that has NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

What happens when using max() and min() on pandas.core.series.Series type that has NaN in it? Is this a bug? See below,

---

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydata = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((100,1)), columns=['No NaN'])
mydata['Has NaN'] = mydata['No NaN'] / mydata['No NaN'].shift(1)

# Both return NaN!
print(min(mydata['Has NaN']), max(mydata['Has NaN']))
# Still why False? Isn't float('nan') a singleton like None?
print(min(mydata['Has NaN']) == max(mydata['Has NaN']))
# But this time works well!
print(min([1, 2, 3, float('nan')]))

print('\n')

# When Series data type that has NaN bumps into min() and max(), what should 
#  I do? E.g.,
try: 
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(mydata['Has NaN'], 10)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e, '\nSeems "range" argument in hist() has problem!')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use the Python built-in `max` or `min` when dealing with `pandas` or `numpy`, especially when you are working with `nan`.

Since 'nan' is the first item of `mydata['Has NaN']`, it is never replaced in either `max` or `min` because (as stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons)):

> The not-a-number values float('NaN') and Decimal('NaN') are special.
>   They are identical to themselves (x is x is true) but are not equal to
>   themselves (x == x is false). Additionally, comparing any number to a
>   not-a-number value will return False. For example, both 3 <
>   float('NaN') and float('NaN') < 3 will return False.

Instead, use the `pandas` `max` and `min` methods:

```
In [4]: mydata['Has NaN'].min()
Out[4]: -176.9844930355774

In [5]: mydata['Has NaN'].max()
Out[5]: 12.684033138603787
```

With regards to the histogram, it seems this is a known issue with `plt.hist`, see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6483) and [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6992).

It should be fairly straightforward to deal with for now, though:

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(mydata['Has NaN'][~mydata['Has NaN'].isnull()], 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but still why doesn't `plt.hist()` work? As stated in the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html), range parameter in function hist() is (x.min(), x.max()) by default. So it _should_ work!

Comment: BTW, I noticed the **docs** link you provided jumps directly to the relevant part rather than the top of the page. It's classy! What trick have you done to the URL associated with the link?

Comment: @Nicholas Sorry, did read your original question about `plt.hist` I think it actually is a bug! See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

you should use Pandas or NumPy functions instead of vanilla Python ones:

```
In [7]: mydata['Has NaN'].min(), mydata['Has NaN'].max()
Out[7]: (-46.00309057827485, 62.430829637766671)

In [8]: min(mydata['Has NaN']), max(mydata['Has NaN'])
Out[8]: (nan, nan)

In [125]: mydata.plot.hist(alpha=0.5)
Out[125]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1a784588>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but still why doesn't `plt.hist()` work? As stated in the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html), range parameter in function hist() is (x.min(), x.max()) by default. So it _should_ work!

Comment: @Nicholas, could you please define: `why doesn't plt.hist() work`? `pandas.plot.hist` works fine for me - see updated answer...

Comment: You're using pandas module. Please try `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `plt.hist()`. But I think juanpa.arrivillaga has already found the problem.